# how do you build sample OpenCV programs that come bundled with the OpenCV source?

Tags: opencv, software-compilation

I have successfully installed OpenCV 2.3.1 on Raspbian image and I would like to build/run some of the C/C++ programs located under the ~/OpenCV-2.3.1/samples directory.

For example, if I wanted to create an executable for ~/OpenCV-2.3.1/samples/cpp/kmeans.cpp how do I do this?

If I do g++ kmeans.cpp I get a whole bunch of compiler errors saying "undefined reference" to OpenCV functions.  So obviously I need to pass it in libraries, but I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the build system provided by OpenCV and enable EXAMPLES compilation. By just issuing the `g++ kmeans.cpp` command you are not linking against any OpenCV library, that's why the compiler complaints about the undefined references (which are defined in the library files).

You may find [this](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/) tutorial handy: it will guide you through the process of building the OpenCV library on a RPi and tell you how to enable examples compilation by setting `BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON`.

Comment: thanks. Also, just wanted to point out that running the following command generated a binary for me:

    g++ convexhull.cpp -o convexhull -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc

Comment: Adding -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON to cmake helped me build the examples on OS X too. Thanks!